# Removing entries from json string in C#

Tags: c#, json, null

I have a json string generated as follows:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(mdata.GetType());

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, mdata);
string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

I want the null entries in the mdata structure not to be present in the json string so is there a straightforward way to do so (without having to parse the json string) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set DataMember attribute option IsRequired to false:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public int Property { get; set; }
```

Also, some libraries can exclude default or null values without modifying DataContract classes. For example, [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question:
[Can JavaScriptSerializer exclude properties with null/default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387755/can-javascriptserializer-exclude-properties-with-null-default-values/2225173#2225173)