# How to remove null value in json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

Hi I'm using the below class

```
Public List<string> name;
Public List<string> midname;
```

Once I serialize it I'm getting the following output like

```
 {"name":[hari],"midname":null}
```

But I want my answer to be like this

```
{"name":[hari]}
```

It shouldn't display the  class attribute that has null value and I'm using c# .net framework.

Comment: What are you using to perform the serialization?  That would be helpful to know to provide an answer...

Comment: I think linq might be able to accomplish this.

Comment: how you serialize, which tool you are using?

Comment: Are you using `json.net`?

Comment: what library are you using to serialize?

Answer (score 24):

The full answer depends on how you're serializing your class.

If you're using data contracts to serialize your classes, set `EmitDefaultValue = false`

```
[DataContract]
class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<string> name;

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<string> midname { get; set; }
}
```

If you're using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), try this instead

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<string> name;

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<string> midname { get; set; }
}
```

Or set it globally with `JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `Json.Net` then You can try this by Decorating your property like this

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public List<string> name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 10):

Like p.s.w.g said, best to serialize properly in the first place. An example of serializing without nulls can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984760/7335973)

e.g.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        objectToSerialize,
        new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked very well

Answer (score 3):

```
private class NullPropertiesConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonExample = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //check if decorated with ScriptIgnore attribute
            bool ignoreProp = prop.IsDefined(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), true);

            var value = prop.GetValue(obj, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, null);
            if (value != null && !ignoreProp)
                jsonExample.Add(prop.Name, value);
        }

        return jsonExample;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes(); }
    }
}
```

The following is how you will utilize the above and it will ignore null values.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new NullPropertiesConverter() });
    return serializer.Serialize(someObjectToSerialize);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569365/188246)

Comment: Great answer with no need to use 3rd party libraries AND with no need of changing the serialized classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JsonConvert from Newtonsoft.json rather than JavaScriptSerializer

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings() 
            { 
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but today with .net6 you can do:

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
public List<string> midname;
```

And you `midname` list will not appear in the serialized object.

Answer (score 1):

string signatureJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(signature, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

Answer (score 0):

In case of using System.Text.Json ([which is a recommendation for performance reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1)). This is another workaround to get rid of null values, in my case is not feasible to use a decorator because of the amount of properties, so let's use a `JsonSerializerOptions` instead:

```
var content = new ContentToParse() { prop1 = "val", prop2 = null };

string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(content, new 
     System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()  { DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull 
    });
//json {"prop1":"val"}
```

Comment: This does not work.  The attributes worked. .NET 6.