# Apply `DefaultValue` to every string properties in serialisation

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Apply `DefaultValue` to every string properties.

#### Context:

The Following class are automatically generated. And Editing them to add those property is a burden. As generated class is quite big, and generated code has a lot of existing property etc. I made a program that open the CS file and use some regex to add the property. but still have to maintain the programme to match the generated file name.

---

With Json.Net, in order to hide empty string in the serialisation result I have to define the default value of those string with `[DefaultValue("")]`.

In the following exemple we have some class and nested class. 
The aim is to hide the empty string in Bar when serialising a Foo item.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Prop1;
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Prop2;
    public int? Prop3;
    public Bar Prop4;
    public Bar[] Prop5;
};

public class Bar
{
    public int Prop1;
    public string Prop2;
    public int? Prop3;
};

public void NullOrEmptyStringTerminator()
{
    var bar = new Bar { Prop1 = 0, Prop2 = "", Prop3 = 0 };
    var bar2 = new Bar { Prop1 = 0, Prop3 = 0 };

    var inputs = new[] {
       new Foo{ Prop1= 1, Prop2="", Prop4= bar, Prop5 = new []{bar} },
       new Foo{ Prop1= 1, Prop4= bar, Prop5 = new []{bar2} },
    };

    var jsonResults = 
            inputs
                .Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        Item = x,
                        NormalSerialisation =
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                                x,
                                Formatting.Indented,
                                new JsonSerializerSettings { }
                            ),
                        CustomSerialisation =
                             JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                                x,
                                Formatting.Indented,
                                new JsonSerializerSettings
                                {
                                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                                })
                    }
                ).ToList();
}
```

#### Test Case:

```
class Foo : 
  int    Prop1 -> Real value 1
  string Prop2 -> No value either "" or null
  int?   Prop3 -> No value null
  Bar    Prop4 -> Real value Bar
  Bar[]  Prop5 -> Real value Bar[]

class Bar :
  int    Prop1 -> No value 0.
  string Prop2 -> Same test than Foo.Prop2
  int?   Prop3 -> Real value 0; Not null
```

The expect result is for both of the input Json.

```
{
  "Prop1": 1,
  "Prop4": {
    "Prop3": 0
  },
  "Prop5": [
    {
      "Prop3": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `DefaultValueHandling`, `NullValueHandling`, and  `[DefaultValue("")]`, are already present in this question. I will update with a C# fiddle and the print of CustomSerialisation. When I get to a PC

Comment: Yeah, you already using `DefaultValueHandling`, but you forgot to add `DefaultValueAttribute` to `Prop2` in `Bar`. Then it's only `Prop1` and `Prop3` (when set to `0`). `Foo` is working, right?

Comment: If you can't modify `Bar`, then you have to [write custom converter for properties containing `Bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18521970/1997232).

Comment: No. Not forget. I have a lot of class. And need some kind of generalisation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty string properties from json serialized object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287224/remove-empty-string-properties-from-json-serialized-object)

Comment: I guess we have a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. However now that is more clear that these classes are "automatically generated" how to you generate them? Do you have any influence in the generation process? Which module/software/whatever generate your classes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `DefaultValueAttribute` in your Bar class. A alternative would also be to set the property to `null`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEoBlT

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputs = new List<object>()
        {new Foo{Prop2 = "" , Bar = new Bar()}};
        foreach (object input in inputs)
        {
            string NormalSerialisation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings{});
            string CustomSerialisation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings{NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore});
            Console.WriteLine("normal:");
            Console.WriteLine(NormalSerialisation);
            Console.WriteLine("custom:");
            Console.WriteLine(CustomSerialisation);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {

        public string Prop2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Bar Bar
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Prop2;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
normal:
{
  "Prop2": "",
  "Bar": {
    "Prop2": null
  }
}
custom:
{
  "Prop2": "",
  "Bar": {}
}
```