# How to use DefaultValueAttribute for property of type object or MyType?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.net for converting the object into json and I am using the `DefaultValueHandling`option in `Json.net` to remove the property with default value. I did that easily for primitive types such as int,string,bool etc but it dont know how to use `DefaultValueHandling` for property of type object or user-defined type.

Please help me to solve this,

**Example**
For primitive types i did like this

```
[JsonProperty("allowPaging")]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool AllowPaging
{
    get { return this.allowPaging; }
    set { this.allowPaging = value; }
}
```

How to do it for property of object types,

```
[JsonProperty("data")]
public object Data
{
    get { return this.data; }
    set { this.data= value; }
}
```

Comment: The following link discussing about this.

try this [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387755/can-javascriptserializer-exclude-properties-with-null-default-values

Answer (score 0):

For object, default value is null. So why do you want to remove it if the behavior will not changed? This attribute is working only for value types and primitives

Comment: Actually in my json i am getting the empty object as `data:{}` its looking awkward that why i tried to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The same concept is discussed and answered in the following kindly. Kindly have a look. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387755/can-javascriptserializer-exclude-properties-with-null-default-values)