# How to Ignore class property from Json Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I am creating a webservice using asp.net 4.0.

I have created a asmx file and creating a User.cs Class. It has 8 Properties.
I have return a service with json format.
If the userlogin is true i need to return all the properties of user.cs, if it's fail i need to return only 2 property.

How to achieve it.

User login is true. It will return all

**{"message":"valid user","BranchId":1,"BranchName":"My branch Name","Id":1,"Name":"admin","Password":"admin","RoleId":1,"Status":1}**

User login is failed i need to retun only **message and Status**. but it will return all like as foloows

{"message":"username or password is invalid","BranchId":0,"BranchName":null,"Id":0,"Name":null,"Password":null,"RoleId":0,"Status":0}

I have google it and get the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization). How to use it based on my login status condition.

If i have used [ScriptIgnore] in my property it will ignore property both case. I need to ignore property when login failed.

My properties like this

```
// Properties
    public int BranchId
    {
        get { return _BranchId; }
        set { if (_BranchId != value) { _BranchId = value; } }
    }

    public string BranchName
    {
        get { return _BranchName; }
        set { _BranchName = value; }
    }

    private String _message;

    public String message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; }
    }
```

My webservice

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void appLogin(String userName, String passWord)
    {
        Admin_AppUserBLL objusr = Admin_AppUserBLL.GetAdmin_AppUserBLL(userName);
        string strResponse = "";
        if (objusr != null)
        {
            if (objusr.Password == passWord)
            {
                objusr.message = "valid username";
                strResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objusr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objusr = new Admin_AppUserBLL();
            objusr.message = "username or password is invalid";
            strResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objusr);
        }
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString());
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387755/can-javascriptserializer-exclude-properties-with-null-default-values) - possible duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Add following attribute on your property and also make it nullable by using "?"

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "BranchId")]
        public int? BranchId{ get; set; }
```

It will ignore if value will be null and also json does not contain these peoperties.

Comment: It shows following error, The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Add reference of NewtonSoft in your application.                                                                      If it is solved your problem please mark solution.

Comment: @Hisanth is using JavaScriptSerializer not NewtonSoft

Comment: It is a part of  Json.net  Refer the following link
  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add reference in Newtonsoft

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

while serialize the object

```
string strResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objusr, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

it will avoid null value property